# How to change the order of magento backend menu

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

how can I change the order of the Magento Admin-Menu (Backend)? Pleas take a look a the picture. For example I want to move "Kundenmeinungen und Bewertungen" between "Kategorien verwalten" and "Attribute". Is that possible and how? Thank you!

http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160311/8uc4k5iy.jpg

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Of course, this is a programming question . There are no settings fot this ind the back end. It is an adjustment in a template or xml-File or something similar.

Comment: You should read [ask] and [mcve]. My lack of understanding that this wasn't a programming question and the lack of answers so far indicate that you've not asked a very clear question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the sort_order of the menu, you can find this in your `etc/adminhtml.xml` file